# iFrame content squeezed into a scrollbox in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, scrollbar

I am experiencing a problem with a dynamically sizing iFrame.  Essentially it works perfectly in IE 7,8,9 but only in Quirks mode and runs correctly in chrome and firefox.  So my problem relates to Standard document modes for ie 7,8,9.

When in IE in standard form it squeezes the content into a scrollbox about 200px in height with a vertical scrollbar only.  I can edit the style to use a specific height i.e 600px instead of height 100% which will look fine...however the nature of the content varies a good bit in terms of height.

Does anybody have any solutions to this?  Seems a bit odd!

Scrolling=no maintains the squeezed content, I just can't scroll down then.  overflow in CSS is doing nothing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that runs in IE 7 +
It uses jQuery

```
MyLibrary = {
    iframeApp: function(options) {
        var $app = $(window[options.name]),
            $appContainer = $(options.wrapperId);

        window.setInterval(function() {
            var frameEl = $app[0].frameElement,
                frameDoc = 0,
                height = 0;

            if (frameEl.contentDocument !== undefined) {
                frameDoc = frameEl.contentDocument,
                height = frameDoc.height || frameDoc.body.offsetHeight;
            } else if (frameEl.document !== undefined && frameEl.document.documentElement !== undefined) {
                frameDoc = frameEl.document.documentElement,
                height = frameDoc.offsetHeight;
            }
            $appContainer.css("height", height);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Thats the javascript code.  Here is the html.

```
<div id="iframe-runner">
    <iframe scrolling="no"frameborder="0"name="myiframe"class="myiframe"src="http://mysrc.com/sweet-i-frame-app"width="100%"height="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        MyLibrary.iframeApp({
            name: "myiframe",
            wrapperId: "#iframe-runner"
        });
    })
</script>
```

---

Running it in one page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="iframe-runner">
    <iframe scrolling="no"frameborder="0"name="myiframe"class="myiframe"src="http://mysrc.com/sweet-i-frame-app"width="100%"height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        iframeApp({
            name: "myiframe",
            wrapperId: "#iframe-runner"
        });
    })
    function iframeApp(options) {
        var $app = $(window[options.name]),
            $appContainer = $(options.wrapperId);

        window.setInterval(function() {
            var frameEl = $app[0].frameElement,
                frameDoc = 0,
                height = 0;

            if (frameEl.contentDocument !== undefined) {
                frameDoc = frameEl.contentDocument,
                height = frameDoc.height || frameDoc.body.offsetHeight;
            } else if (frameEl.document !== undefined && frameEl.document.documentElement !== undefined) {
                frameDoc = frameEl.document.documentElement,
                height = frameDoc.offsetHeight;
            }
            $appContainer.css("height", height);
        }, 500);
    }
</script>
```

MAKE SURE you update the iframes SRC

Comment: You can change the rate of the change for smoother transitions/less lag time.  You can also just verify that the previous height is less than the current height then adjust the size of the iframe to +25 px bigger for a "growing" effect.

Comment: sorry where are you supposed to place mylibrary?

Comment: That was just an example if you had some sort of library.  But if you do not, then `iframeApp: function(options) {` could be turned into just a simple function (remove `MyLibrary = { ... }` all together and just have `function iframeApp(options) {`.  Then just call `iframeApp({your-options})` in the page you need it.  `iframeApp` can be located in some script file thats imported in.

Comment: how would you get this all to run in a single page?  I am not having much luck, either it does nothing or throws undefined errors

Comment: @shicky Hey, check out the edits.  It works just fine for me to do it in this one page.

Comment: sorry to keep asking dumb questions but what should the src for the iframes be?  I am using this on dynamic content so for example this will be working on a page called Rates_and_Values.ashx and Products.ashx

Comment: Its the src of the page you want to bring in.  So if your page is located at www.yoursite.com/my-content/iframe.php  Then put that in the iframe src

Comment: As mentioned it is dynamic content though, so the page src will be different depending on what page is clicked on, I think I see what I need to do to make this work though...inevitably I will fail!

Comment: The content can be dynamic, thats not a problem.  its the growing of an iframe that is required.  If you have different content depending on what page is clicked welcome to the internet.  You got to solve problems one at a time.  Solve the problem of iFrames not fitting properly in their spot or not growing depending on the content within them... then solve the different pages depending on the setup information.

Comment: Well unfortunately I can't get this to work for any of the pages.  As mentioned everything works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE with quirks.  While trying to get your iframeApp to run in a single page it keeps throwing:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'offsetHeight': object is null or undefined

On this line: height = frameDoc.height || frameDoc.body.offsetHeight;

Comment: my guess is that your not passing in the correct "name" to the function.

Comment: Accepted as i'm sure it does work and will help some people.  Unfortunately for me it still throws javascript errors after numerous attempts: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'offsetHeight': object is null or undefined.  I got my iframe functioning correctly in IE7 using html height 100% however it has the same issue in IE8/9 still.

Thanks for your help Michael